# Removing SSL port from URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Initially, the port number 448 was included in the URL of my client. Now, they use the port 448 no longer. The problem is: the existing website address (in the form of "http://www.example.com:448") is not used. But there are many existing URLs referred by many blogs or sites. When visitors click the URL containing ":448", an error message "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" appears in the browser. Is there any way to redirect to the new site URL (http://www.example.com instead of http://www.example.com:448) even if visitors click the existing URLs containing the port number? The new site has bee rebuilt with WordPress recently.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could configure that the old url (with the port) to redirect requests to the new address. 
Depending on the webserver your site is hosted on, this could all mean a configuration on your server side.

Comment: @bandreas, Thank you very much